# Main Content Overlaps On Zoom In Browser

Tags: html, css

So I've been working on a website in html5 and css3, but I've ran into a problem. My wrapper is 960px, and within that wrapper I have 2 DIVs, 1 being floated left, and the size of that one is 240px, and 1 floating right, with the size being 695px. In browsers there is a zoom feature, which I assume simulates different resolutions. So when I zoom out a couple of clicks, my right floated div, expands and goes underneath my left floated div. Take a look at the screenshots:
Normal: http://puu.sh/iMCEn/eff5baff4d.png
Zoomed: http://puu.sh/iMCGQ/98145b5788.png

Here is my CSS:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0;}

@font-face {
    font-family: reckoner;
    src: url(../fonts/Reckoner.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: champ;
    src: url(../fonts/champ.ttf)
}

body {
    background-color: #333333;
}

#wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 150px auto 0 auto;
}

#banner {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    font-family: reckoner;
    font-size: 65px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    margin-left: 10.5px;
}

#main {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    border: 1px solid #404040;
    outline: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
    font-family: champ;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #262626;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid #404040;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #404040;
}

#nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#e5e5e5;
    font-size:17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 695px;
    min-height:500px;
    background-color: #262626;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid #404040;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AAA GAMING - TRIPLE A GAMING</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="banner">AAA GAMING</div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>Donate</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>Chat</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>How To Connect</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>Application</li></a>
                        <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Post your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zoom feature does not simulate different resolutions, a better way to do this is resizing the browser window.  Zoom is notorious at breaking layouts due to rounding errors so I wouldn't fret too much over it, but in this case fixing the problem is easy.

I replicated this problem in Chrome.

Floats are often glitchy like this because if anything happens to make the stuff fitting in the remaining space beside a float, wider than the floating element, they'll get bumped down below the floating element.  This is what is happening here.  In general, I also avoid placing two floating elements side-by-side.

The two basic solutions are:

1. Make the element narrow enough that it doesn't happen
2. Use something besides a float (like absolute positioning)

(2) is a long-term solution I'd recommend for new layouts.  But a quick solution to implement (1) in this case is to change the margin of the #content element.  Under:

```
margin: 10px;
```

Add the line:

```
margin-left: -10px;
```

This fixes the problem on my browser at all zooms down to 25%.  It also doesn't visibly effect the layout at all in any other way, because it doesn't affect the width of the visible part of the element itself, it only effects the width of its container which can force it to get bumped down.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `main` container is changing width on the browser zoom.  If you set the `min-width` style on it, it will stop shrinking beyond the breaking point.  I set it to `min-width: 965px;` and that seemed to stop the breaking on zoom (at least in Chrome).